# How do I do a legal two (or three) column signature component?

Tags: multicolumn

I need to do a two or three column ending to a legal document as shown in the attached image. I need some help setting it up? Should I use some sort of box or column? I need the column of closing brackets and the signature to be vertically centred with respect to the column on the left.

[image: legal form ending]

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I ended up going with three side by side minipages; the centre was only wide enough for the closing bracket and a little padding on the left and right.

Answer (score 3):

With some abuse of math mode…

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
$\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
SWORN (OR AFFIRMED) BEFORE ME \\
at Vancouver, in the Province of British Columbia, \\
the 3rd day of March, 2020 \\[2cm]
$\overline{\mbox{\rule{0pt}{2ex}A commissioner for taking Affidavits\ \ }}$\\
or a Notary Public
\end{tabular}
\right\rbrace
\displaystyle\frac{}{\makebox[5cm][l]{\rule{0pt}{2ex}Merry Jane Doe}}
$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant based on egreg solution

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
$
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{)}}
SWORN (OR AFFIRMED) BEFORE ME \\
at Vancouver, in the Province of British Columbia, \\
the 3rd day of March, 2020 \\ %[2cm]
\\
\\
\\
$\overline{\mbox{\rule{0pt}{2ex}A commissioner for taking Affidavits\ \ }}$\\
or a Notary Public
\end{tabular}
\displaystyle\frac{}{\makebox[5cm][l]{\rule{0pt}{2ex}Merry Jane Doe}}
$
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The difference is to use `)` as the "right delimiter" of the tabular column `@{)}` (plus a few empty lines)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines?

```
% sigprob.tex SE 531499 Two or thre col signature

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\textwidth}|l} 
SWORN (OR AFFIRMED) at Vancouver more text & \\
                         & Mary Jane Doe \\
A Commissioner more text & \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Tweak as necessary.